# Finding the chemical name of SnMg₂O₄

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, nomenclature, reference-request

Can somebody help me in identifying the name of $\ce{SnMg2O4}$?
Other examples are $\ce{ZnAl2O4}$ (zinc aluminate), $\ce{ZnIn2S4}$ (zinc thioindate).

Please kindly provide the reference if possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\ce{Mg2SnO4}$ Magnesium Orthostannate

$\ce{MgSnO3}$ Magnesium Metastannate

Answer (score 3):

$\ce{SnMg2O4}$ and $\ce{ZnAl2O4}$ belong to [spinel group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spinel_group) ($\ce{A^4+B^2+2O4}$ and $\ce{A^2+B^3+2O4}$, respectively) and should be treated as solid solutions of ternary oxides:

- $\ce{SnMg2O4}$: **tin(IV) dimagnesium oxide** or **dimagnesium tetraoxostannate(IV)**;
- $\ce{ZnAl2O4}$: **zinc dialuminium oxide** or **zinc tetraoxodialuminate**.

$\ce{ZnIn2S4}$ is a [thiospinel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thiospinel_group) ($\ce{A^2+B^3+2S4}$):

- $\ce{ZnIn2S4}$: **zinc diindium sulfide** or **diindium tetrathiozincate**.

In general, IUPAC Red Book [1, p. 237] discourages from using *ortho-* and *meta-* prefixes with only a few exceptions (for more details refer to [What does the prefix meta mean in inorganic chemistry?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/40506/what-does-the-prefix-meta-mean-in-inorganic-chemistry)), and suggests leaving the [formula unit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formula_unit) with a structural type notation as, for example, $\ce{SnMg2O4}$ (*spinel* type):

> A mineral name may, however, be used to indicate the structure type. Where possible, a name that refers to a general group should replace a more speciﬁc name. For example, large numbers of minerals have been named that are all spinels, but which have widely differing atomic constituents. In this case, the generic name ‘*spinel* type’ should be used rather than the more speciﬁc names chromite, magnetite, *etc*. The generic mineral name, printed in italics, should be accompanied by a representative chemical formula. This is particularly important for zeolite types.[...]
>
> Examples:
>    1. $\ce{FeCr2O4}$ (*spinel* type)
>    2. $\ce{BaTiO3}$ (*perovskite* type)

#### References:

1. IUPAC “Red Book” Nomenclature of Inorganic Chemistry; Connelly, N. G., Ed.; IUPAC Recommendations; *Royal Society of Chemistry Publishing/IUPAC: Cambridge, UK*, **2005**. ISBN 978-0-85404-438-2.