# What do the prefixes meta, ortho, pyro mean in inorganic chemistry?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, nomenclature

In inorganic chemistry, when is the prefix **meta** used? (as in **metaborate** and **metasulphite**)
What about the terms **pyro** and **ortho** (as in **orthophosphorous acid**)?

For example, I recently came to know about the prefixes **per** and **hypo** which are used to refer to the highest and lowest oxidation states of an element respectively (like **perchlorate** and **hypochlorite**).

Are there any terms and conventions I should be aware of?

Comment: What does meta means in the compound "meta aluminate"?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

In the older literature, the prefixes “hypo-”, “per-”, “ortho-”, “meta-”, and “pyro-” were used in some cases for the distinction between different acids with the same characteristic element.

The prefix “hypo-” was used to denote a lower oxidation state, and the  prefix “per-” was used to designate a higher oxidation state. (The prefix “per-” is not be confused with the prefix “peroxo-”.)

> $\ce{HClO}$ hypochlorous acid
> $\ce{HClO2}$ chlorous acid
> $\ce{HClO3}$ chloric acid
> $\ce{HClO4}$ perchloric acid

The prefixes “ortho-” and “meta-” were used to distinguish acids differing in the formal content of water.

> $\ce{H3BO3}$ orthoboric acid
> $\ce{(HBO2)$_n$}$ metaboric acid
>
> $\ce{H4SiO4}$ orthosilicic acid
> $\ce{(H2SiO3)$_n$}$ metasilicic acid

The prefix “pyro-” was used to designate an acid that is formally formed by removing one molecule of water from two molecules of an ortho-acid.

> $\ce{H4P2O7}$ pyrophosphoric acid $(\ce{2 H3PO4 -> H4P2O7 + H2O})$.

Various traditional names are retained for use in IUPAC nomenclature, though the number of retained names has been reduced with each succeeding edition of the IUPAC recommendations. The Second Edition (1970 Rules) of the IUPAC *Nomenclature of Inorganic Chemistry* (published in 1971) still included all of the above-mentioned prefixes; however, the approved use was limited to only some selected retained names. The further development and the current situation of the nomenclature are well explained in @Jan’s thorough [answer](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/40517/7951).

Comment: Hey sorry but I still Did not get the ortho and meta part! What do you mean by formal content of water?

Comment: @KaranSingh For example, metaboric acid can be formed by condensation (dehydration) of orthoboric acid. Heating of orthoboric acid releases one equivalent of water to give metaboric acid: $\ce{$n\,$H3BO3 -> (HBO2)$_n$ + $n\,$H2O}$. Therefore, the formal difference is just the content of one equivalent of water.

Comment: @Loong          But meta phosphoric acid is not formed by loosing one water molecule from orthophosphoric acid. So what is general equation?

Comment: @Loong What's the difference between -ous and -ic?

Comment: The ending -ous is used for a low oxidation number. -And -ic is used for higher oxidation numbesr.

Comment: What does meta means in the compound "meta aluminate"?

Answer (score 21):

> Are there any terms and conventions I should be aware of?

**Yes.** IUPAC publishes the [Red Book](https://iupac.org/what-we-do/books/redbook/) also called [Nomenclature of Inorganic Chemistry](https://iupac.org/what-we-do/books/redbook/) which is the authoritative source of nomenclature terms. Its current version (2005; the only one I will be referencing above the horizontal rule) does *not* contain the word *pyro* meaning that that is unacceptable for inorganic nomenclature purposes.

*Ortho* and *meta* are sometimes allowed as traditionalised common names. *Ortho* only in the cases of *ortho*-periodic acid and *ortho*-telluric acid and their derivatives ($\ce{IO(OH)5}$ and $\ce{Te(OH)6}$, respectively) to distinguish them from periodic acid ($\ce{HIO4}$) and telluric acid ($\ce{H2TeO4}$). *Meta* is only allowed for *metasilicate* and *metaborate*, both describing long-chain anions whose systematic name would be *catena*-poly[(oxidoborate-μ-oxido)($1-$)] (or with a *dioxidosilicate* instead of *oxidoborate*) to distinguish them from silicate ($\ce{SiO4^4-}$)  and borate ($\ce{BO3^3-}$), respectively.

The usage ‘**ortho*-phosphoric acid’ and the like has been deemed unnecessary and obsolete because there is no ‘other’ form of phosphoric acid that one could want to differ between. The former *meta*-forms are better described as what they actually are: *cyclo*-triphosphoric acid, for example.

Note that the prefixes *hypo* and *per* are also non-systematic as per IUPAC every instance where they occur can also be named systematically. However, they remain as acceptable alternatives in many instances due to their simplicity and commonness, e.g. *peroxide, periodic acid, hypochlorite.* Note that not always does *per* refer to the highest oxidation state: *persulphate* is still a sulphur(VI). However, there is a peroxido ligand attached to it.

---

Historically, the terms were also used in an often non-systematic way. *Ortho* is Greek and means *true,* implying that an *ortho*-something be the true form of something: Hence *ortho*-phosphoric acid for ‘the true’ monophosphoric $\ce{H3PO4}$.

*Meta* means *after* in Greek, so Aristotle’s *Metaphysics* was a book that was conventionally placed *after* Aristotle’s *Physics* in the library of Alexandria. Thus, *meta* compounds are the ones which arrived *after* *ortho* compounds by some mechanism. *meta*-Phosphoric acid was seen as a monohydrate of $\ce{P2O5}$ while *ortho*-phosphoric acid was the ‘true’ trihydrate of $\ce{P2O5}$. ($\ce{P2O5} + \ce{H2O} = 2 \ce{HPO3}$; while the formula for phosphorous pentaoxide is actually $\ce{P4O10}$ and that of *cyclo*-triphosphoric acid would be $\ce{H3P3O9}$.) The logic is that the ‘true’ hydrate needs to be hydrated, to *afterwards* give the *meta*-hydrate.

*Para* is not used in inorganic chemistry to the best of my knowledge.

*Pyro,* meaning *fire* in Greek, is a prefix for something that has to do with being burnt in some way. Hence, pyrophosphates were initially prepared by heating hydrogen phosphates to red glow. A few decades later, researchers realised that the ‘pyro’-phosphate was, in fact, a diphosphate. Likewise, *pyruvic* acid was originally prepared by heating of tartaric acid. According to a quick search across Wikipedia, *pyro* is only applicable to phosphate and sulphate and their respective acids meaning the dehydrated dimer. Personally, I have never encountered *pyro*-anything outside biochemical lectures (and my school’s biology classes) when connected to phosphate. You can consider all *pyro*s entirely obsolete and replaced by *di-* (disulphuric acid, disulphate, diphosphate, etc.).

Comment: Also, a question:) Does it all also mean that *orthovanadate* and *metavanadate* are obsolete and shouldn't be used?

Comment: @andselisk To the best of my knowledge yes.