# Is there a systematic way of remembering the names and formula of Oxoacids of Phosphorus?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, nomenclature

My question is exactly what the title says: Is there a systematic way of remembering the names and formula of Oxoacids of Phosphorus ?

I am asking this because I find it very daunting to memorize their names and chemical formula and also a significant number of questions are asked regarding them.

Comment: You mean what really? IUPAC naming? And "P, S, Cl etc" looks like joke. Do you have idea how many oxoanions sulfur alone makes?

Comment: http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/40506/what-does-the-prefix-meta-mean-in-inorganic-chemistry http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/43826/problem-in-understanding-nomenclature-of-mineral-acids

Comment: Chemistry is daunting?!? Who doesn't like playing with LEGOs - The periodic table is the ultimate LEGO set.