# Why is H5PO5 not called as phosphoric acid?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, nomenclature

Recently, my course of inorganic chemistry has begun, and in the nomenclature of inorganic acids, our professor told that phosphoric acid is $\ce{H3PO4}$ and phosphorous acid (orthophosphorous acid) is $\ce{H3PO3}$.

He explained to us that usually, the oxyacid of the highest oxidation state end with the suffix -ic.

So my question is, even in $\ce{H5PO5}$, phosphorous exhibits its highest oxidation state, so why isn't it called phosphoric acid, instead of $\ce{H3PO4}$?

Comment: So, the highest oxidation state acids arent supposed to end with -ic?

Comment: what are the rules for nomenclature then?

Comment: Because there's no such thing as H5PO5!

Answer (score 4):

$\ce{H3PO4}$ is called *orthophosphoric acid*$\ce{^{[3]}}$. The prefix *ortho*- generally applies to the highest hydroxylated acid know either in free state or in salts or esters etc. *pyro*- and *meta*- denotes successive stages of dehydration. No provision is made in I.U.C(International Union of Chemistry) rules for naming the **highest possible** hydroxylated acid **if they are hypothetical in any way** but they are designated by a prefix *holo*- proposed by the German commission. So, in this case $\ce{H5PO5}$ is called *holophosphoric acid*.

But this type of nomenclature has been declared obsolete (see: [What do prefix ortho, meta and pyro mean in chemistry](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/40506/what-do-the-prefixes-meta-ortho-pyro-mean-in-inorganic-chemistry/40517#40517)) and shouldn't be used. Also see: [When to use -ous and -ic while naming acids.](https://chemed.chem.purdue.edu/genchem/topicreview/bp/ch2/names.html#acids)

**Notes and References**

1. [Inorganic Syntheses, Volume 2](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=walWQrTRNK4C&pg=PA260&lpg=PA260&dq=holophosphoric%20acid&source=bl&ots=SoRi7yFhRD&sig=ACfU3U3w4EwvhDDB4gpUKVNCebXqLYdT3w&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjtkIi2w4DqAhWE63MBHdKrBVgQ6AEwAXoECAgQAQ#v=onepage&q=holophosphoric%20acid&f=false)
2. [The nomenclature of mineral acids](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/43826/the-nomenclature-of-mineral-acids/45160)
3. The name "orthophosphoric acid" can be used to distinguish $\ce{H3PO4}$ from other "phosphoric acids ([phosphorus acid series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phosphoric_acids_and_phosphates))". Nevertheless, the term "phosphoric acid" often means $\ce{H3PO4}$; and that is the current IUPAC nomenclature. ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phosphoric_acid))