# Aromatic nomenclature, when to use numbers or prefixes?

Tags: aromatic-compounds

When you're naming aromatic nomenclature compounds, when do use numbers, such as 2,4-diiodonitrobenzene and when do you use prefixes such as p-xylenene? Thanks! I hope that makes some sense

Answer (score 1):

1,4-dimethylbenzene and p-xylene are both equally correct nomenclatures. You could also say 4-methyl toluene if you wanted. I personally prefer the first example because it allows me to visualize the molecule immediately.

As for 2,4-diiodonitrobenzene, this is indicating three substituents. You have the nitro group, and two iodo groups - one *para* to the nitro, and one *ortho* to the nitro.

Answer (score 0):

Recurring to *ortho*, *meta*, *para* constrains the description to two subsitutents, and more often seen for simple "tradtional"compounds; like your example of *p*-xylene, or something like *o*-cresol.

Using numbers allows more flexibility, not only in regard of the number of subsitutents and their relative position to each other, but in reference to a hetero-aromatic ring system, too.

Addendum:

Related / almost duplicate to [this](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/61153/origin-of-ortho-meta-para#comment104133_61153).  Somehow I thought "this is not new" ...