# Benzene ring position labeling (ortho vs para)

Tags: aromatic-compounds, terminology, history-of-chemistry

Why is the ortho position on a benzene ring next to the primary carbon and not in the opposite position, as ortho means "straight", not "next to" as in para?

Comment: Not sure, but I'm glad it turned out O-M-P, because it being alphabetical order offers a great mnemonic for new students.

Comment: What alphabet are you referring to? In English, M-O-P is alphabetical order, and O-M-P doesn't work.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arene_substitution_pattern#Origins

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Origin of "ortho", "meta", "para"](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/61153/origin-of-ortho-meta-para)