# Relate phosphamic acid with phosphoric acid

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, acid-base

It is a simple question, but I am not able to figure it out how the formula of phosphamic acid, which is developed from phosphoric acid. In other words, I want to know how to relate it with phosphoric acid? Also in naming some acids we use meta like in, trimetaphosphamic acid, my question is meta is used for what?

Please help me understand. Thanks.

Comment: Not able to understand from this link

Comment: I edited question now.

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/40506/what-does-the-prefix-meta-mean-in-inorganic-chemistry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/amidophosphoric%2Bacid):

> An acid $\ce{PONH2(OH)2}$ derived from phosphoric acid by replacement
>   of one hydroxyl group by an amido group is called  *phosphamic acid*.
>   It is also called *phosphoramidic acid*

For the 'meta' part, see this - [What does the prefix meta mean in inorganic chemistry?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/40506/what-does-the-prefix-meta-mean-in-inorganic-chemistry)

Comment: While we appreciate your contribution to the site, it would be preferable to not answer questions, that do not comply with our [homework policy](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/141/).